# Instead of battery why we don't use some perpetual energy source? Atomic Energy?

Tags: electric-engine, electric-aircraft

Right now the biggest issue of the electric plane is carrying a large battery to store energy proportional to its consumption for long-range, to increase range we use a larger battery. Even solar planes need batteries.
Why not develop some kind of small reactor that generates energy and has a very compact size. Reducing the size of battery energy direct transfer to the motors.

Comment: While I understand the context of your question here, I think this one is better for Engineering or Physics SEs.  The short answer is "regulatory/political forces prevent nuclear reactors in private hands" but the longer answer is that you're basically asking "Why don't we just invent a better mousetrap?"

Comment: Nuclear power is ultimately steam power. Guess why nobody has tried building a steam airplane?

Comment: You build an actual, functioning perpetual energy source and the world will beat a path to your door step.

Answer (score 5):

Because there is no such thing as a perpetual energy source. Atomic energy eventually runs out and all reactors have to be refueled. Stars all run out of fuel as well and flame out in some interesting, and often spectacular way. Putting a nuclear reactor in an aircraft has already been explored and it was found that properly shielding it would make the airframe too heavy to fly.

[Why nuclear powered aircraft do not exist.](https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2019/01/elderly-pilots-who-could-have-flown-nuclear-airplanes/580780/)